# Get unique records from table avoiding all duplicates based on two key columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table Trial_tb with columns p_id,t_number and rundate. 
Sample values:

```
p_id|t_number|rundate
=====================
111|333    |1/7/2016||
111|333    |1/1/2016||
222|888    |1/8/2016||
222|444    |1/2/2016||
666|888    |1/6/2016||
555|777    |1/5/2016||
```

pid and tnumber are key columns. I need fetch values such that the result should not have any record in which pid-tnumber combination are duplicated. For example there is duplication for 111|333 and hence not valid. The query should fetch all  other than first two records.

I wrote below script but it fetches only the last record. :(

```
select rundate,p_id,t_number from
(
select rundate,p_id,t_number,
count(p_id) over (partition by p_id) PCnt,
count(t_number) over (partition by t_number) TCnt
from trialtb
)a
where a.PCnt=1 and a.TCnt=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
select 
    p_id,t_number 
from
    trialtb
group by
    p_id,t_number 
having 
    count(*) = 1
```

or do you need the run date too?

```
select 
    p_id,t_number,max(rundate) 
from
    trialtb
group by
    p_id,t_number 
having 
    count(*) = 1
```

Seeing as you are only looking items with one result using max or min should work fine

Comment: Yes, need rundate as well.

Comment: I added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The [having](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) clause is ideal for this job.  Having allows you to filter on aggregated records.

```
-- Finding unique combinations.
SELECT
    p_id,
    t_number
FROM
    trialtb
GROUP BY
    p_id,
    t_number
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
;
```

This query returns combinations of `p_id` and `t_number` that occur only once.

If you want to include `rundate` you could add `MAX(rundate) AS rundate` to the select clause.  Because you are only looking at unique occurrences the max or min would always be the same.